# How to determine that the input text occurred after clicking on the inline button in telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I have such a user case for a telegram bot:

1. press /menu, get inline menu
2. In the menu, click on the feedback button
3. enter the feedback in the text and inform that we have accepted the feedback
4. return the next menu message

I still don't get how to determine in text handler that moment with the message sent only after pressing the button, and not in the arbitrary text entered at any time.

I also use telegraph to develop my bot and so far only managed to create a keyboard with callback_query payload.

Comment: Please only tag libraries that you are using and please explain in your question how you use them :)

Answer (score 0):

The link has good information: Finite State Machine.
https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/finite_state_machine/index.html
This is how I implemented something similar...

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
import os as OSis

bot = Bot(token=OSis.getenv("TOKEN"), parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

# State class:
class UserAnswer(StatesGroup):
    City = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    # add button:
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    start_button = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Select a city', callback_data="town_id")
    markup.add(start_button)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello from the bot!", reply_markup=markup)

# Handler for displaying the result of a button click: start_button
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == "town_id")
async def button_press(call: types.callback_query):
    """Displaying a list of cities in the form of buttons"""
    list_cities = ['Washington', 'Montgomery', 'Phoenix', 'Atlanta', 'Boise', 'Frankfort', 'Boston', 'Springfield',
                   'Helena', 'Nashville']

    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    for name in list_cities:
        keyboard.row(types.KeyboardButton(name))
    await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Your city:", reply_markup=keyboard)
    # Set the status for the 1st response:
    await UserAnswer.City.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=UserAnswer.City)
async def get_answer_correct(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Get answer
    answer_city = message.text
    # Saving a variable
    await state.update_data(answer1=answer_city)
    # In variable 'data' will contain all the saved variables in the form of a dictionary
    data = await state.get_data()
    # get answer from 'data'
    user_city = data.get("answer1")
    print('answer1 =', user_city)

def main():
    executor.start_polling(dp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```